# SwiftUI accentColor change

Tags: ios, swiftui

Default SwiftUI accent color is a kind of Blue. I want to make it White on Dark theme and Black on White theme.

Though when I set for example `.accentColor(.red)` disabled buttons are properly grayed out and enabled buttons are red.

But when I set `.accentColor(.primary)` I don't see any difference between disabled and enabled buttons. Why is like that?

I expect enabled to be for example white and disabled greyed out.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can define a color on Assets named for example "accent", as White for Dark and Black for the rest. Then call that color for the accentColor. It works. Reference Asset Color

```
.accentColor(Color("accent"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

after your `NavigationLink` or `NavigationView` to disable using accent colors (blue by default).